# Apply collocation from listo of bigrams with NLTK in Python

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I have to find and "apply" collocations in several sentences. The sentences are stored in a list of string. Let' focus on only one sentence now.
Here's an example:

```
sentence = 'I like to eat the ice cream in new york'
```

Here's what I want in the end:

```
sentence_final = 'I like to eat the ice_cream in new_york'
```

I'm using Python NLTK to find the collocations and I'm able to create a set containing all the possible collocations over all the sentences I have.
Here's an example of the set:

```
set_collocations = set([('ice', 'cream'), ('new', 'york'), ('go', 'out')])
```

It's obviously bigger in reality.

I created the following function, which should return the new function, modified as described above:

```
def apply_collocations(sentence, set_colloc):
    window_size = 2
    words = sentence.lower().split()
    list_bigrams = list(nltk.bigrams(words))
    set_bigrams=set(list_bigrams)
    intersect = set_bigrams.intersection(set_colloc)
    print(set_colloc)
    print(set_bigrams)
    #  No collocation in this sentence
    if not intersect:
        return sentence
    #  At least one collocation in this sentence
    else:
        set_words_iters = set()
        # Create set of words of the collocations
        for bigram in intersect:
            set_words_iters.add(bigram[0])
            set_words_iters.add(bigram[1])
        # Sentence beginning
        if list_bigrams[0][0] not in set_words_iters:
            new_sentence = list_bigrams[0][0]
            begin = 1
        else:
            new_sentence = list_bigrams[0][0] + '_' + list_bigrams[0][1]
            begin = 2

        for i in range(begin, len(list_bigrams)):
            print(new_sentence)
            if list_bigrams[i][1] in set_words_iters and list_bigrams[i] in intersect:
                new_sentence += ' ' + list_bigrams[i][0] + '_' + list_bigrams[i][1]
            elif list_bigrams[i][1] not in set_words_iters:
                new_sentence += ' ' + list_bigrams[i][1]
        return new_sentence
```

2 question:

- Is there a more optimized way to to this?
- Since I'm a little bit inexpert with NLTK, can someone tell me if there' a "direct way" to apply collocations to a certain text? I mean, once I have identified the bigrams which I consider collocations, is there some function (or fast method) to modify my sentences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply replace the string "x y" by "x_y" for each element in your collocations set:

```
def apply_collocations(sentence, set_colloc):
    res = sentence.lower()
    for b1,b2 in set_colloc:
        res = res.replace("%s %s" % (b1 ,b2), "%s_%s" % (b1 ,b2))
    return res
```